# How to locate drawable folder in Android

Tags: android, resources

According to this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

developer page says, create a XML file which should holds the icons to indicate state of resource. But by default a new project is created, this Drawable folder does not exist but i will be having 4 diff folder indicate different resolution images.

I forcefully created a folder named Drawable and place the XML file and used in my application, but unfortunately my application throws exception saying resource is NULL. How to overcome this issue?

Where do we have to place the XML file?, should we make individual XML file and place in different resource folders? kindly advice me

Here is the image of folder structure.

[image]

If i use the ic_tab_artist, my app crashes. here is the full source

```
package simple.tab.proj;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SimpleTabActivity extends TabActivity  {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistsActivity.class);

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artists",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Do the same for the other tabs
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistsActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("albums").setIndicator("Albums",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistsActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("songs").setIndicator("Songs",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);

    }



    public static class ArtistsActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            TextView textview = new TextView(this);
            textview.setText("This is the Artists tab");
            setContentView(textview);

            //setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Here is my ic_artist_tab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- When selected, use grey -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_artists_grey"
          android:state_selected="true" />
     <!-- When not selected, use white-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_artists_white" />
</animation-list>
```

Comment: You put the folder under res folder? can you show us the xml?

Comment: i hv put the entire source code plus image pls hv a look

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your "crash".

Comment: you shouldn't have those .png files in the drawables folder. Can you post the content of ic_tab_artists.xml?

Comment: @Chopin, pls have a look

Comment: @CommonsWare, from logcat only i came to know the problem is related to resource, if i add image directly it works well but if i give XML file, app crashes. This is the exception "android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_tab_artists.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020001"

Comment: Try using `<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">` at the root element, instead of `animation-list`.

Comment: @Chopin, you rock... it work fantastic... thanks for your help... but may i know what exactly was the problem...

Comment: I'm glad could help you! I don't know what was the problem either. Maybe android couldn't inflate correctly the xml and return null ^^

Answer (score 1):

> I forcefully created a folder named Drawable and place the XML file and used in my application, but unfortunately my application throws exception saying resource is NULL. How to overcome this issue?

Android is case-sensitive. The directory needs to be `res/drawable/`, not `Drawable`.

> should we make individual XML file and place in different resource folders?

One XML file in `res/drawable/` should suffice, though the individual drawable resources pointed to by your `StateListDrawable` may need different versions for different densities.

Comment: Hi, i tried the way u said, my app crashes, i have posted the code. pls hv a look once..

Comment: @LLL: Beyond the problem pointed out by Chopin in the question comments, try doing Project > Clean in Eclipse, as that clears up many strange behaviors with resources.